# SharePoint search returns result with servername address

Tags: search, search-results, enterprise-search

Normally, SharePoint search returns results that contains their link to item, **http://domain/Documents/doc1.docx** for instance. However, with that document item, its link to item becomes **http://servername/Document/doc1.docx**.

Are there any configuration that specifies the link to item would be used with domain, not with servername?

Comment: please check the document in the library where it is uploaded, what is their it's showing? domain or server name?

Comment: Do you have multiple AAM Zones?

Comment: one of my co-worker has resolved the issue. In addition, it's on production environment and I had not taken a look at it carefully. It's probably due to Server Name Mapping, inside Search Service Application

Answer (score 1):

Is this happening with only one document? Because it might be that you will start seeing every document like this in the future.

In this case, it is probably a misconfiguration of the Alternate Access Mappings.

Can you check that the http://domain is still configured correctly in there?

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly old but you probably already found the answer on Central Admin:

Central Admin > Manage Service Applciations > Search Services > Server Name Mappings (side bar) should take care of that issue. You just put in what the address (the server part) in the index, and then what the address should be. (effectively it should be replaced).